# What to use instead of a main loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I need a loop for `main` in Haskell. I've tried this:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  do
    putStrLn "do something"
    main
```

Is the above code the correct approach to take? Will this infinite recursion cause an overflow?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is fine; no stack overflow will occur. Stack overflows in Haskell (and, indeed, any non-strict language) are different to those in other languages; they arise from accumulating large values without ever evaluating them, but you're not accumulating anything here; just sequencing an infinite chain of actions. You can think of it like this: Once the line is printed, the action is discarded, and control passes straight onto `main`; nothing is kept on the stack because there's nothing that has to be returned to.

It's the same reason you can iterate through an infinite list without running out of memory: as the program goes further down the list, previous list cells are reclaimed by the garbage collector as they're no longer required. In this case, the previous sequencings are reclaimed, as there's no reason to keep around an action you've already performed.

That said, a nicer way to write this particular example is:

```
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = forever $ putStrLn "do something"
```

Of course, this won't work if your loop is ever intended to terminate. `forever` is itself implemented with recursion, so there's no benefit other than readability to doing this.

Comment: why no stack overflow will occur if I do so? what's Haskell's recursive different from C's

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully explain why a bit better.

Comment: Stacks are different because Haskell (like several other languages) guarantees "tail calls" do not allocate stack frames: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: @ChrisKuklewicz: Actually, Haskell doesn't guarantee tail call optimisation, and in fact it's perfectly possible to write a tail-recursive Haskell program that causes a stack overflow. But there's a [closely-related concept](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) that does apply, commonly called [tail recursion modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons). Still, even then it's just an implementation detail; the Haskell report doesn't specify any details of evaluation strategy at all.

Comment: @ehird: you are right, the Haskell 98 report does not mention tail calls.  The wikipedia page claims: "Tail call elimination is thus required by the standard definitions of some programming languages, such as Scheme,[2][3] languages in the ML family, and Haskell." but has no citation for Haskell.  Perhaps that needs clarification...

Comment: Furthermore, the `main` call in `main` is not in a tail position, because the definition is `main = (>>=) (putStrLn "do something") main`.  So it is `(>>=)` which is tail called by `main`.  The definition of `(>>=)` in the IO monad may or may not tail call its second argument.  That said, I'd expect the recursion to run without growing the stack.

Comment: augustss, should that be `(>>)`?

Answer (score 2):

What you observe is the result of "tail call elimination / optimization", which is nothing special to Haskell. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call

Comment: Actually it's a bit different in Haskell, due to laziness. Some things that wouldn't be optimized in strict languages *are* able to be optimized in Haskell. However, if you have a strict Haskell function, then TCO behaves roughly the same as in strict languages that implement this feature.